# chartjs not using full width in bootstrap column

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm using [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/) to plot a donut inside a `row>col` as follows in a react component with this [library](https://github.com/houjiazong/react-chartjs2) (Not sure it's important but I'll mention it anyway...):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">....</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <RC2 data={chartData} type='donut' />
    </div>
</div>
```

The graph is drawing nicely and updates when there is new data. So that's awesome. The problem is that the donut doesn't take the full width of the column and ends up being tiny! See image below: 
[image]

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Typically chart JS would set the height or width based on the aspect ratio, so if you have either of them specified, the library would calculate the other one and apply it. You should check the styles getting applied on the canvas to be sure. Or, set an inline style of height:auto to be sure that other classes are not interfering with it.

Comment: Try using [react-vis](https://github.com/uber/react-vis) instead, easier and more flexible to use. It has a `FlexibleWidthXYPlot` class made just for that: adaptive width/height chart.

Comment: @GuillaumeAcard They don't seem to have donuts...